# php json output to html table with additional text boxes and post back to a php with the input for updating the mysql

Tags: php, html, json

I have a php with a json output where i need to load it to the html table.

```
[{"item":"VM1","request_by":"kevin"},{"item":"VM2","request_by":"kevin"},{"item":"VM001","request_by":"kevin"}]
```

This I need to add to the html table with two additional fields and a button.

```
VM01| kevin | "Anne" | "Pass" | Submit Button
```

where the button will make a post to another php to update to the mysql database.

I have already written the php functions, but can anyone help me writing the html code?

Thank you in advance. I searched a method to do, yet, with my limited knowledge, i can't find a solution for it.

this is what i was trying:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.getJSON("http://localhost/back_p/listall.php",
            function (data) {
                var tr;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tr = $('<tr/>');
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].item + "</td>");
                    tr.append("<td>" + data[i].request_by + "</td>");
                    $('table').append(tr);
                }
            });
        </script>
    <body>
```

the data is not loading as well

Comment: Did you write any html code? SO isn't a free code service. Unless you show us your effort, and where exactly you are stuck, we can't really help you.

Comment: @PaulKaram it is added now. I know it is not free :)

Comment: where are you calling the function to initiate it? You aren't saving the JSON to a variable

Comment: @ezw i am to be honest, blindly trying things as i do not know how to get the php localhost/json.php output data to the html table and get two data inputs and post it back to the localhost/post.php

Comment: `$.getJSON("http://localhost/back_p/listall.php",` needs to be `var data = $.getJSON("http://localhost/back_p/listall.php";` first of all and then you need to pass that to your function when you call it

Comment: `$('table').append(tr);` needs to be either `$('.table').append(tr);` if table is class or `$('#table').append(tr);` if table is ID

Answer (score 0):

//EDIT: This is for PHP. You obviously need it in JavaScript. Wrote this before your edit

[json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode)

```
// In your example, you already have json_encoded...
$text = json_encode([["item"=>"VM1","request_by"=>"kevin"],["item"=>"VM2","request_by"=>"kevin"],["item"=>"VM001","request_by"=>"kevin"]]);

// You just need the json_decode to convert to PHP variable
print_r(json_decode($text));

/*
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => VM1
            [request_by] => kevin
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => VM2
            [request_by] => kevin
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [item] => VM001
            [request_by] => kevin
        )
)
*/

$text = json_decode($text);

foreach($text as $item)
{
    echo $item->item.PHP_EOL;
    echo $item->request_by.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Here is my test for javascript. You may put it back into a function if you want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var data = [{"item":"VM1","request_by":"kevin"},{"item":"VM2","request_by":"kevin"},{"item":"VM001","request_by":"kevin"}];

    var tr;

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        tr = $('<tr/>');
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].item + "</td>");
        tr.append("<td>" + data[i].request_by + "</td>");
        $('#table').append(tr);
    }
});
</script>
<table id="table"></table>
```

Comment: THank you very much. can you please let me know how to get the json data from the php as well. it is in the http://localhost/json.php... additionally, this goes in to the script inside the body html right?

Comment: This converts JSON to PHP variable, allowing you to use the JSON result with PHP. How do you  show data to users in PHP?

Comment: Now with your edit to your question, it is apparent that you need it in JavaScript rather then PHP

Comment: Hi i got it working thank you!, but how to add two more text input fields and a button to the each line and get that output to make a php post request?